# C# - Dynamically create array of which the amount of indexes are variable

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a program that uses:

```
// the assignments of hardcoded ids and memoryIndex are for the sake of this question
int id1 = 1;
int id2 = 2;
int id3 = 3;
int id4 = 4;
int memoryIndex = 0;

int[][][] sequence;

sequence[id1][id2][id3] = memoryIndex;
```

I want to use something dynamic with a variable amount of keys defined at runtime, so I could also have 4 or more ids that belong to a sequence. I can't afford a lot of checks because speed is a greater concern than memory. How could I accomplish this in C#?

Comment: What does that mean:  "I want to use something dynamic"?

Comment: @Gaber-ber defined at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say take a look at the C# Array class.  It has several methods for creating arrays with multiple dimensions.  For example, Array.CreateInstance Method (Type, Int32[]) where the second parameter is an array indicating the length of each dimensions.  A sample using your code would look like this:

```
int id1 = 1;
int id2 = 2;
int id3 = 3;
int id4 = 4;

int[] dimensions = {2, 3, 4, 5};
int memoryIndex = -1;

var sequence = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), dimensions);

sequence.SetValue(memoryIndex, new int[]{id1, id2, id3, id4});
```

Here's a link to the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfs8044k(v=vs.110).aspx